# My Dropdown menu works right on every browser but IE 7. Why?

Tags: jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm making some basic drop down menus based on [this tutorial](http://designreviver.com/tutorials/jquery-css-example-dropdown-menu/) So its all dandy except for IE7. It appears when you hover on it but when you move the mouse from the main element to the ones below it it hides again.

```
/* General */
#cssdropdown { position:absolute; right:0px; top:0px; font-size:medium; font-weight:bold; }
#cssdropdown, #cssdropdown ul { list-style: none; }
#cssdropdown, #cssdropdown * { padding: 0; margin: 0; color:Navy; text-decoration:none; }

/* Head links */
#cssdropdown li.headlink 
{ 
    width: 150px; 
    float: left;
    background-color: #e9e9e9; 
    text-align: center; 
    height:35px;
}
#cssdropdown li.headlink a { display: block; padding:7px;} /*7px*/

/* Child lists and links */
#cssdropdown li.headlink ul { display: none; text-align: left; background-color:#e9e9e9; } 
/*#cssdropdown li.headlink:hover ul { display: block; }*/ <--I've tried this via JS below
#cssdropdown li.headlink ul li a { padding:5px;} 
#cssdropdown li.headlink ul li a:hover { background-color: #333; color:White; }
```

And here's the jQuery I used per their instructions to show the menu as an IE fix. (Note it works identical when I use pure CSS or CSS & jQuery even in IE 7. All other browsers work fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('li.headlink').hover(
            function () { $('ul', this).css('display', 'block'); },
            function () { $('ul', this).css('display', 'none'); });
    });
```

and finally my HTML:

```
<ul id="cssdropdown">
        <li class="headlink">
            <a href="../Pages/MainMenu.aspx">Main Menu</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="www.google.com">Google</a></li>
                <li><a href="www.yahoo.com">Yahoo</a></li>
                <li><a href="www.msn.com">MSN</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
 </ul>
```

I do have jQuery linked properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove `height:35px;` from `li.headlink` and [it will work](http://jsbin.com/iheso3/3/edit).

Comment: That did it. So how should I set the height of the Menu. I don't want to set the height of the sub elements since they could need more then 1 line for text, but Not specifying the height for the main element seems strange. Now I have to tweak my header bar to match the menu's height. What if the menu changes its height?

Comment: You could set the height of the `<a>` inside the `<li>`, and set the `<li>`'s vertical padding and margin to 0.

Answer (score 0):

On their page they are using plain JS on one of the examples. Does it work when you try this code instead of the jquery code?

```
        var lis = document.getElementById('cssdropdown').getElementsByTagName('li');
    for(i = 0; i < lis.length; i++)
    {
        var li = lis[i];
        if (li.className == 'headlink')
        {
            li.onmouseover = function() { this.getElementsByTagName('ul').item(0).style.display = 'block'; }
            li.onmouseout = function() { this.getElementsByTagName('ul').item(0).style.display = 'none'; }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be the IE z-index issue.

Set the z-index on the two position:relative elements header and content to fix:

```
      #header { 

          z-index:2; 

      } 

      #content { 

          z-index:1; 

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem last week (or week before), for me it was the sub menu ul needed to have a width declaration of the same width as the li.

Answer (score 0):

This works for Me :
 I Used jQuery 1.10.2 if it matters..

```
if (/msie 7\./ig.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())) {
    $("ul li ul li").each(
        function () {
            $(this).css("width", $(this).parent().width() + "px");
        }
    );

    $("ul li ul").each(
        function () {
            var ParentPos = $(this).parent().offset();
            $(this).css({
                "top": (ParentPos.top + $(this).parent().height()) + "px",
                "left": ParentPos.left + "px"
            }); // end css for This                             
        } // end function/each             
    );

    $("ul li ul li ul").each(
        function () {
            $(this).css("margin-top", "3px"); // end css for This   
        }
    );

} // end if IE 7 Bug -- B.Frederickson -- acey99
```